# Splitting column in PySpark: how to ensure that output is array of int, but with empty arrays for a certain character

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data column that looks like

`./.` or `0/1`

and should be split into arrays of integers with the string `/`, with the caveat that `.` should be empty.

my first attempt to do so:

```
df2 = df2.withColumn('genotype_indices', split(col("genotype_index"), "/").cast("array<int>")).alias("genotype_indices")
```

but the problem is that `.` is cast as `0`, which isn't correct.

I really don't want to have to use user-defined function, as these can make the notebooks unusuably slow.

How can I get `.` to cast as `None` or empty, and all other integer strings as integers in PySpark?

Comment: is the column length fixed?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala column length can be variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is converted as `0` because `.` is used in float numbers for decimals and it's equivalent to `0.0` so when casting as an int it gives `0`.

You can remove the dots before spliting using `regexp_replace` function :

```
df2 = df2.withColumn('genotype_indices', split(regexp_replace(col("genotype_index"), "\\.", ""), "/").cast("array<int>"))
```

Comment: for some reason, this solution cannot find the column `genotype_index` and I'm baffled why

Comment: he uses df.withColumn, urs has df2.withColumn.. that might be it

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi I corrected it, it was a minor parenthesis issue